# HERE Maps schema with specific primary key

Tags: here-api

I'm looking for a way to define a schema in the HERE Cloud with a specific primary key. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you add more details to your question? From the current description, it's completely unclear which service/product you are trying to use and what is a problem.

Comment: Let me try to clarify my question:
HERE offers Geovisualization and it is shown here (https://developer.here.com/geovisualization/documentation/topics/overview.html) that a schema needs to be created for the data - either by uploading it with the specific column headers or by explicitly defining it beforehand. I tried this using the JSON format and I now wonder whether I can define I column as primary key in JSON.

Comment: No, We don't provide primary key support yet in Geovisualization.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the answer already provided in comment:

"No, We don't provide primary key support yet in Geovisualization."